# How can I force the installation of the Virtualbox Extension pack?

Tags: 11.04, virtualbox

I have a BIG problem with VirtualBox; every time I try to add or install the newest extension pack, it gives an error; at first, it asked me to add my user to the vboxuser group, which I already did, but still can't install the extensions pack.

How can I force Virtualbox to install it?

[image: Error]

It says, Failed to install extension pack—the path to the file, and the error itself.

Here I tried running it on the root terminal, but Virtualbox crashes.

```
 uri-MS-7267 uri # virtualbox
 Qt CRITICAL: Qt-subapplication(20282)/kdeui (KIconLoader): Error: standard icon theme "oxygen" not found! 

 Qt WARNING: QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 3
 Qt WARNING: QPainter::setCompositionMode: Painter not active
 Qt WARNING: QPainter::end: Painter not active, aborted
 Qt WARNING: QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 3
 Qt WARNING: QPainter::setCompositionMode: Painter not active
 Qt WARNING: QPainter::end: Painter not active, aborted
 Segementation fault
```

When trying to install the Extpack from the terminal i get this:

```
 uri@uri-MS-7267 ~ $ sudo VBoxManage extpack install Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.0.10- 72436.vbox-extpack
 0%...
 Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
 VBoxManage: error: Failed to install "/home/uri/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-  4.0.10-72436.vbox-extpack": The installer failed with exit code 1: VBoxExtPackHelperApp:   error: The owner is not root: '/usr/lib'
```

And I get nothing when using gksu.

```
 uri@uri-MS-7267 ~ $ gksu VBoxManage extpack install Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.0.10-72436.vbox-extpack
 uri@uri-MS-7267 ~ $
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try to install the extension pack using the command line:

```
sudo VBoxManage extpack install <package file>
```

Some random things to check:

- Virtualbox version and extension pack version must match.
- Files on /usr/lib/virtualbox must be owned by root.
- /usr/lib itself must be owned by root, too as Uri himself find.

Comment: I'm getting an error when installing that way, seems like it's still the same as above.

Comment: i also tried with gksu and the command you suggested, i get no errors in return but, the extension pack doesn't show as installed.

Comment: I added some blind shots, maybe one of them works.

Comment: I've downloaded the previous version 4.0.8.7.1778 of both the Vbox deb and the ext pack, i've installed the deb and attempted to install the Extpack, and i still get the same error. :(

Comment: I also checked with PCMANFM the permissions of /usr/lib/virtualbox and it says root.

Comment: usr/lib/ however says, the owner is my user, should it be like that?.

Comment: Looking at my netbook /usr/lib is owned by root :O, i don't know how or why that happened >.<.

Comment: Just fixed it, changed it's owner, thanks for the hints :)

Comment: BTW, that was exactly what the error message was saying all this time... LOL.

Comment: Yeah, now i get it... >_< haha *facepalm*

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be saying you need to be root, so run it as root, and then install the pack.

Comment: It crashes when i run it with gksu or plain sudo, with QT warnings about me not having the oxygen theme (?).

Comment: @Uri you should probably report a bug O.o

Comment: Where do i report it?

Comment: @Uri I'm not sure where they track their bugs.

Comment: http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Bugtracker

Answer (score 0):

For me, this problem was cause by the wrong ownership of some folders and files in `/usr`.

```
root@mybox-01:~# ls /usr -la
total 152
drwxrwxr-x  11  501   501  4096 Nov 27 15:03 .
drwxr-xr-x  26 root root   4096 Dec 25 15:00 ..
drwxrwxr-x   2  501   501 57344 Dec 28 09:27 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   4096 Dec 25 19:45 games
drwxr-xr-x  35 root root   4096 Dec 25 19:45 include
drwxrwxr-x 167  501   501 36864 Dec 28 09:27 lib
drwxrwxr-x   3  501   501  4096 Nov 27 15:03 lib64
drwxrwsr-x  10 root staff  4096 Dec 24 18:34 local
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  12288 Dec 28 09:27 sbin
drwxrwxr-x 278  501   501 12288 Dec 28 09:27 share
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root   4096 Dec 28 09:27 src
```

The fix was to do `chown root.root -R /usr`

Then run the command `VBoxManage extpack install <package>` file again..

I'm not sure how this was caused but I hope the "fix" doesn't break anything else on my system..